# Getting undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when I try to use my MongoLab database with Mongoid and ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a Rails application on Heroku that is supposed to connect to a MongoLab database. My issue is any command that attempts to access the database in any way results in

> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

This includes seeding the db. My mongoid.yml is as follows

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] %>

development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: dev_database
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
```

This mongoid.yml works fine for another ROR application I have using the same version of Mongoid (3.0.1), so I am unsure why it is giving me issues here. MONGOLAB_URI is defined in the environment. I'm fairly certain the issue must be with the database connection, but I am unsure what. Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

EDIT:

I just tried this to no avail as well...

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] %>
      options:
        skip_version_check: true
        safe: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot Heroku defaults to ruby 1.9.2, adding

> ruby '1.9.3'

to my gem file fixed it.